# Gif animation "Echo" problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I created this animation in premiere and exported it as a gif.

Originally the file had a chroma key green background which I removed manually (frame by frame) in Photoshop. When I did "save for web" -> save", the output file suddenly has an "echo" shown in the animation (as if the older frame is not overwritten by the newer one).

Any suggestions how I can fix that?

Please note that I am still pretty much a beginner in Photoshop and the solution needs to be written explaining it with detailed steps so I can actually fix it :D

Thanks guys!

file: [http://i.imgur.com/atq4jEX.gif](https://i.imgur.com/atq4jEX.gif)

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that each frame is keeping the content of the previous one. I'm assuming you have each frame as its own layer. You need to turn on a solid white layer for each frame, so that it'll hide the previous one. Or make sure on each frame the layer that contains that content is the only one visible.